# regarding ObservableCollection in c#

Tags: c#, observablecollection

i found a piece of code that use ObservableCollection but they can use list or any other collection related classes. can anyone tell me what is the benifit of using ObservableCollection.

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> empData = new ObservableCollection<Employee> 
        {
            new Employee{Name="Diptimaya Patra", Contact="0000", 
                EmailID="diptimaya.patra@some.com", Country="India"},
            new Employee{Name="Dhananjay Kumar", Contact="00020", 
                EmailID="dhananjay.kumar@some.com", Country="India"},
            new Employee{Name="David Paul", Contact="1230", 
                EmailID="david.paul@some.com", Country="India"},
            new Employee{Name="Christina Joy", Contact="1980", 
                EmailID="christina.joy@some.com", Country="UK"},
            new Employee{Name="Hiro Nakamura", Contact="0000", 
                EmailID="hiro.nakamura@some.com", Country="Japan"},
            new Employee{Name="Angela Patrelli", Contact="0000", 
                EmailID="angela.patrelli@some.com", Country="Japan"},
            new Employee{Name="Zoran White", Contact="0000", 
                EmailID="diptimaya.patra@some.com", Country="Scotland"},
        };
```

please discuss in detail. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This interface exposes events that allow consumers of your collection to be notified when the contents of the collection change.

This is mainly used when binding in WPF, for example let's say we have an `ObservableCollection<string>`:

```
ObservableCollection<string> MyStrings
{
    get
    {
        // return a collection with some strings here
    }
}
```

and this control in XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings}" />
```

The `ComboBox` will show the strings inside your `ObservableCollection`. So far, this would have worked just fine with a `List<string>` as well. However, if you now add some strings to the collection, for example:

```
<Button Click="AddSomeStrings" Content="Click me!" />

private void AddSomeStrings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyStrings.Add("Additional string!");
}
```

you will see that the contents of the `ComboBox` will be immediately updated and the string will be added to the list of options. This is all accomplished using `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Answer (score 7):

The benefit of `ObservableCollection` is that it raises the [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event every time the collection is changed, and the [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653376.aspx) event every time one of the properties of the collection is changed.

In a similar way, if you want an object (which is not a collection) to raise an event every time one of its properties change, you should make it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: thanks for your answer...can u please make me understand through code regarding the advantage of ObservableCollection because i never use it before.....plzzz explain.

Comment: @Thomas, There are a lot of examples online. Here is one: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32416400/observablecollection--notification-when-item-has-changed-not-the-collection.aspx