# How to delete all the item from list in c# windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Hi all i am working on a windows phone chat application and i have save all the user chat in a local DB and now i want to clear conversation and i am not able to delete all the chat and my following code will delete one item at a time following code i am using:

```
var Del_Chat = dbConnDelete_User.Query<SavedMsg>("select * from SavedMsg
                               where ChatUserId='" + totalSeletion + "'").FirstOrDefault();
dbConnDelete_User.Delete(Del_Chat);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want clear everything from the list, you can do this

```
  List<MyClass> myList = new SList<MyClass>();
  myList.Clear(); //Remove all elements from the list
```

This work for `ObservableCollection` too

```
ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyObservable = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>
();
MyObservable.Clear();
```

I would suggest you to use [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed. it will be reflected in your user interface. [Pros of Observable collection instead of List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851549/1876572)